# cordova.js causes reference error 'require is not defined'

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ngcordova

I'm wish to use **ngCordova** to detect the network state of a device.  However, as soon as I include **cordova.js** I get an error -

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined (cordova.js:23)

I've installed and am successfully running **Node.js** and **Cordova**, and I've downloaded and installed **ngCordova** [following the instructions here](http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/).

I have also installed the **network-information** plugin via the **Cordova CLI** -

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information

As per the documentation this is the code sample that I'm using (and to clarify, the error occurs as soon as I include cordova.js, so even without this code snippit I still get the error;  this is show my end goal) -

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngCordova']);

app.controller('myCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$cordovaNetwork', function($rootScope, $scope, $cordovaNetwork){

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

        var type = $cordovaNetwork.getNetwork()

        var isOnline = $cordovaNetwork.isOnline()

        var isOffline = $cordovaNetwork.isOffline()


        // listen for Online event
        $rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:online', function(event, networkState){
            var onlineState = networkState;
        })

        // listen for Offline event
        $rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:offline', function(event, networkState){
            var offlineState = networkState;
        })

    }, false);

}]);
```

In my **index.html** file I've made sure that I have declared the files are required in the order specified -

1. `angular.min.js`
2. `ngCordova.min.js`
3. `cordova.js`

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Have you tried changing
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$cordovaNetwork', function($scope, $cordovaNetwork) to app.controller('myCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$cordovaNetwork', function($rootScope, $scope, $cordovaNetwork).

All the dependancy and order needs to be correct in array and function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that is not the issue (although I have updated my question to include your suggestion).  To clarify, the error occurs as soon as I include `cordova.js`, so even without the code snippit included I still get the error.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The answer here is that the **Cordova** CLI automatically includes `cordova.js` and any necessary dependancies when you build the application.

The `cordova.js` file is placed in the `www` directory, so all you have to do is include that file -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

It seems illogical to reference a file that you are not inculding, but once you get your head around how the CLI works it makes sense.

The main problem for beginners is that it's quite poorly documented.  In fact, **Cordova** as a whole seems to be poorly documented, not so much in terms of quantity but rather the relevance - so much is for old versions.  It's a fantastic project though, and hopefully this is something that will be addressed in the near future.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But after putting cordova.js to proper place. The error: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined is being gotton from the lines: 
var channel = require('cordova/channel');
var platform = require('cordova/platform');

at cordova.js

How can we handle this problem?